# How can I search user meta by a partial key name?

Tags: user-meta

Im setting up a section in a user account where the user can block off certain days, right now its adding the meta as follows

```
unavailable-days_1: ["16/06/2021"]
unavailable-days_2: ["18/06/2021"]
unavailable-days_3: ["12/06/2021"]
```

And the search box will basically be a date range field where they specify a time range 15/06/2021 - 18/06/2021 for example and if the user has specified a date they become unavailable.

But for now I'm trying to grab the user meta keys to basically check if the key begins with **unavailable-days** then give me the value, then I can check to see if its in the range of the submitted dates.

I've tried the following:

```
foreach (get_user_meta($user->ID) as $metaKey => $metaValue) {
    array_push($userArray, array($metaKey, $metaValue);
}
```

but ends up just pulling the values and not the key.

Comment: user meta keys are not unique, they don't need to have numbers on the end, just give them all the same key and use `false` instead of `true` when you retrieve the values, you'll get an array of values instead of a singular value. This is a problem you do not need to solve

Comment: Then you could do something like this: `$days = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'unavailable-days', false ); foreach ( $days as $day ) { ..... }`. Otherwise keeping the numbers on the end of the user meta keys will make your life very difficult. E.g. what happens if the user deletes the second day? Now your numbers have a gap! And you have to keep track of how many entries there are too.

Comment: Im currently using a plugin for this so cant really alter the way it gets added without altering the source, to be honest I was kind of hoping it would just add one variable and as you said just be an array rather then _1 _2 might have to just find a crude way of doing it.

Comment: Unfortunately no, there is no simple solution here, it's possible the plugin you're using provides an API that returns these values but you would need to ask their support, no such API exists in WordPress core outside of retrieving all user meta, then filtering out what you don't want manually in PHP using a loop